# SaaS application needs to export/backup data to individual customer sites

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, saas

We have a cloud based SaaS application and many of our customers (school systems) require that a backup of their data be stored on-site for them.

All of our application data is stored in a single MS SQL database. At the very top of the "hierarchy" we have an "**Organization**". This organization represents a single customer in our system. Each organization has many child tables/objects/data. Each having FK relationships that ultimately end at "Organization".

We need a way to extract a **SINGLE** customer's data from the database and bundle it in some way so that it can be downloaded to the customers site. Preferably in a SQL Express, SQLite or an access database.

For example: `Organization -> Skill Area -> Program -> Target -> Target Data` are all tables in the system. Each one linking back to the parent by a FK. I need to get all the target data, targets, programs and skill areas per organization and export that data.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to do this within SQL Server, a C# service, or a 3-rd party tool?

I need this solution to be easy to replicate for each customer who wants this feature "turned on"

Ideas?

Comment: Is this for strictly backup ONLY or restore as well?

Comment: Why can't you use ssis to create a backup per org?

Comment: @KrisIvanov They will only need to restore it if something happens to our company or our data. Its just to make them feel secure with their data.

Comment: I would use BIDS to create data migration SSIS, just like @Phil suggested

Comment: If the purpose of this is to allow the customer to download their data and access it outside of your SaaS application, wouldn't it make more sense to find out why so many of them want to access it outside of your system and build those features into it? Just thinking long term here, you're more likely to retain people if they can do everything they need to do in your application. Either way, I think a little more detail on **why** they want the information would be helpful. You may not need to dump **all** the data for them, just what they need.

Comment: @Brian they aren't USING this data for anything. Our customers are mostly schools and Special Education centers. These centers have tight regulations on FERPA and HIPAA. Many of them just want a COPY on their premises in case of a disaster. They just don't fully trust the "Cloud".

Comment: Oh I understand, so you're looking for a way to simply allow them to backup the data into a nice tight neat little single-file package that can be re-uploaded to your server if need be at a later time? If that's the case... lemme move this to a response because I don't have room here lol

Comment: It seems to me that you would want to add foreign keys from all of your sub tables to the organization table.  There are many benefits such as reducing the number of joins required to validate a user within an organization has access to an object.  I realize it is no small task making that change, but it would make this and other future tasks a bit easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a big fan of using messaging to propagate data at the moment, so here's a message based solution that will allow external customers to keep a local, in sync copy of the data which you provide on the web.

The basic architecture would be an online, password secured and user specific list of changes which have occurred in the system. 
At the server side this list would be appended to any time there was a change to an entity which is relevant to the specific customer. 
At the client would run an application which checks the list of changes for any it hasn't yet received and then applies them to its local database (in the order they occurred).

There a a bunch of different ways of doing the list based component of the system but my gut feeling is that you would be best to use something like RSS to do this.

Below is a practical scenario of how this could work:

1. A new skill area is created for organisation "my org"
2. The skill is added to the central database and associated with the "my org" reccord
3. A SkillAreaExists event is also added at the same time to the "my org" RSS with JSON or XML data specifying the properties of the new skill area
4. A new program is added to the skill area that was just created
5. The program is added to the central database and associated with the skill area
6. A ProgramExists event is also added at the same time to the "my org" RSS with JSON or XML data specifying the properties of the new program
7. A SkillAreaHasProgram event is also added at the same time to the "my org" RSS with JSON or XML data specifying an identifier for the skill area and program
8. The client agent checks the RSS feed and sees the new messages and processes them in order
9. When the SkillAreaExists event is processed a new Skill area is added to the local DB
10. When the ProgramExists event is processed a new Program is added to the local DB
11. When the SkillAreaHasProgram event is processed the program is linked to the skill area

This approach has a whole bunch of benefits over traditional point in time replication.

- Its online, a consumer of this can get realtime updates if required
- Consistancy is maintained by order, at any point in time in the event stream if you stop receiving events you have a local DB which accuratly reflects the central DB as at some point in time.
- Its diff based, you only need to recieve changes
- Its auditable, you can see whats actually happened not just the current state.
- Its easily recoverable, if there's a data consistency issue you can revert the entire DB by replaying the event stream.
- It allows for multiple consumers, lots of individual copies of the clients info can exist and function autonomously.

We have had a great deal of success with these techniques for replicating data between sites especially when they are only sometimes online.

Answer (score 1):

While there are some very interesting enterprise solutions that have been suggested, I think my approach would be to develop a plane old scheduled backup solution that simply exports the data for each organisation with a stored procedure or just a number of select statements.

Admittedly you'll have to keep this up to date as your database schema changes but if this is a production application I cant imagine that happens very drastically.

There are any number of technologies available to do this, be it SSIS, a custom windows service, or even something as rudimentary as a scheduled task that kicks off a stored procedure from the command line.

The format you choose to export to is entirely up to you and should probably be driven by how the backup is intended to be used. I might consider writing data to a number of CSV files and zipping the result such that it could be imported into other platforms should the need arise.

Other options might be to copy data across to a scratch database and then simply create a SQL backup of that database.

However you choose to go about it, I would encourage you to ensure that the process is well documented and has as much automated installation and setup as possible. Systems with loosely coupled dependencies such as common file locations or scheduled tasks are prone to getting tweaked and changed over time. Without those tweaks and changes being recorded you can create a system that works but can't be replicated. Soon no one wants to touch it and no one remembers exactly how it works. When it eventual needs changing, or worse it breaks, you have to start reverse engineering before you can fix it.

In a cloud based environment this is especially important because you want to be able to deploy as quickly as possible. If there is a lot of configuration that needs to be done you're likely to make mistakes or just be inconsistent. By creating a nuke-and-repave deployment you have a single point that you can change installation and configuration, safe in the knowledge that the change will be consistent across any deployment.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you have one large database for all the clients, you use relations which lead to the table organization to know which data for which client, and you want to backup the data based on client => organization.

To backup the data you can use one of the following methods:

- As the comments from @Phil, and @Kris you can use SSIS for automated backup, check [this link for structure backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248775/export-tables-objects-and-data-based-on-select-criteria), and check this link for how to [Export a Query Result to a File using SSIS](http://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/ssis-export-query-result-to-a-file/) and instead of file do it to access or SQL Server database.
- Build an application\service using C# to select the data and export it manually, need time but customization has no limits.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at StreamInsight?

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/complex-event-processing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When I've had to deal with backups of relational data in the past (in MySQL which isn't super different in terms of capability from MSSQL that you're running) is to create a backup "package" file which is essentially a zip file with a different file extension so that windows won't let users open it.

If you really want to get fancy, encrypt the file after zipping it and change the extension. I presume you're using ASP for your SaaS and since I'm a PHP-geek, I can't help too much with the code side of things, but the way I've handled this before was for a script that would package an entire Joomla site and Database for migration to a new server.

```
//open the MySQL connection
$dbc = mysql_connect($cfg->host,$cfg->user,$cfg->password);
//select the database
mysql_select_db($cfg->db,$dbc);

output( 'Getting database tables

');

//get all the tables in the database
$tables = array();
$result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES',$dbc);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $tables[] = $row[0];
}

output( 'Found '.count($tables).' tables to be migrated.
Exporting tables:
');

$return = "";

//cycle through the tables and get their create statements and data
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

    $return.= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$table.";\n";
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
    $return.= $row2[1].";\n";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
        for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) {
            $row[$j] = mysql_escape_string($row[$j]);
            $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
            if (!empty($row[$j])) {
                $return.= "'".$row[$j]."'" ;
            } else {
                $return.= "NULL";
            }
            if ($j<($num_fields-1)) {
                $return.= ',';
            }
        }
        $return.= ");\n";
    }
}
```

That's the relevant portion of the code in PHP that loops the database structure and stores the recreation script in $result which can then be output to a file.

In your case, you don't want to recreate the databases, but rather the data itself. You've compounded the issue slightly since you have a SaaS that is prone to possible data structure changes which you'll need to be able to account for. My suggestion would be this then:

Use a similar system to the above to dump the relevant data from the individual tables. I'm simply pulling all the data, but you could pull only the parts that pertain to the individual user by using JOIN statements and whatnot. Dump the contents of each table's insert/replace statements into a file named after the table. Create a file called manifest.xml or something of that sort and populate it with the current version of your SaaS application, name/information, unique ID, etc of the client exporting the data.

Package all those files into a ZIP file, change the extension to whatever you want, encrypt it if you desire, etc. Let them download that backup file and you're set.

In your import script, you will need to read the version number of the exported data and compare it to some algorithm that can handle remapping the data based on revisions you make later on. This way if you need to re-import one of their backups later, you can correctly handle transitioning the data from when they pulled the backup to the current structure of the data in that table now.

Hopefully that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because you keep all the data in just one database, it will always be difficult to export/backup data on customer basis.

Even if you implement such scenario now, you will end up with two different places you need to maintain/change/test every time you change the database schema (fixing bugs, adding new features, optimization, etc).

I would recommend you to partition the data, say, by using a database per organization. Then you change your application just once (mainly around building a connection string for the specified organization), and then you can safely export/backup each database separately in a way you want it.

It also gives you a lot of extra benefits "for free" such as scalability and the ability to dedicate resources on per-organization base (whether it is needed in the future). 
Say, you have a set of small and low priority (from a business point of view) organizations, and a big and high priority one. So you will be able to keep a set of small low priority databases on one server, but dedicate another one for that specific important big one.
Or if your current DB server is overloaded (perhaps you have A LOT of data and A LOT of requests to the database), you can simply get another cheap server and move half of the load without any changes in your system...
You still need to write something in order to split the existing big database into several small ones, but you do it just once, and after it is done this "migration tool" can be thrown away so you don't need to support it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [SyncFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608)?
Have a look at [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/williamryan/archive/2007/11/13/filtering-data-ado-net-synchronization-services.aspx) article!
It explains how to sync filtered data between databases using Sync Framework.
You can sync to the customer's database or sync to your own empty db and then export it as a file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought about using an ORM? (Object Relational Mapper)

I know, and use, LLBLGen Pro (so I can talk only about the feature of this specific ORM)
Anyway, with LLBLGen you can reverse-engineer the DB and create a hierarchy of class that map the tables and relations of your DB.

Now If all the data of a customer is reachable via relations, I can tell to my ORM framework to load a single costumers (1 row of a specific table) and then load all the related data in the related table.

If the data is not too complex, it should be possible.
If you have hundreds of self referenced tables or strange relations, it may be undoable, it depend upon your data.

If all the data of a single customer is, say, 10'000 rows in 100 tables, it will probably work.
If all the data of is 100'000 rows in 1000 tables it "may" work if you have some times, and a lot of memory.
If all the data is 10'000'000 you probably cant load it all at once, and you'll need a more efficient way.

Anyway, if you can load all the data at once, then you'll have a nice "in memory" graph with all the data of a single customer, and then you can serialize this data, or project it on a dataset (obtaining a set of datatable/relations) and then serialize the dataset.

Using an ORM to load and export all the data of a single customer as explained, probably, is not the most efficient way of doing things, but when doable it's a simple and cheap way.
Naturally, with or without ORM, you can find hundreds of different way to export this data :-)

Answer (score 0):

For you design, you should have sharded your database for customers.

However, as you have already developed the database design, I suggest you to create a temp database and create the new tables in this temp database using the FK relation.

For this, you need to sort the tables based on the FK relationship and create them in the temp database.

Then, select the table data from the source database and insert them in the temp database.

You can also use this technique to shard your database and revamp your database design.

Aravind